# What does: "Нас встречают" mean?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have tried to decode: "Нас встречают" with a slovar (book) and through   various machines but it result into something that does not make sense. Would it perhaps mean something like "we are waited" or they are "waiting for us" since the verb встречать is involved?

Comment: When asking for translation, please provide some context (the whole phrase and some background would be ideal). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're still on your railroad journey book, this means "someone's meeting us" or "someone's picking us up" (at the airport or a train station).

Answer (score 1):

The exact translation would depend on the context.  Assuming you're talking about arrivals (e.g. to a station, airport, etc.) and somebody waiting for the arriving paraty, it could be something like

> Someone's waiting for us

If you edit your question with more details on the context, I'll update my answer accordingly.